# Print checked value from radio button

Tags: php

So,
i have this value :

```
$row['status'];
```

How can i mark as checked the value which is checked?
This is the form:

```
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" value="1" /> Mbyllur<br />
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" value="0" /> Hapur<br />
```

So, if the value is 1 the radio button should be checked..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" <?php if($row['status'] == 1){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> value="1" /> Mbyllur<br />
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" <?php if($row['status'] == 0){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> value="0" /> Hapur<br />
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly :)
I'm accepting it in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the variable is set first or you will get a `Undefined variable: row`-Error and then check the value of it:

```
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" <?php if(isset($row['status']) && $row['status'] == 1){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> value="1" /> Mbyllur<br />
<input type="radio"  id="status2" name="status2" <?php if(isset($row['status2']) && $row['status2'] == 0){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> value="0" /> Hapur<br />
```

Edit: You should not use an ID ("status") more than one time on a page. An ID is an unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="1" <?=($row[ 'status' ] ? "checked" : "") ?>/>
<input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="0" <?=($row[ 'status' ] ? "" : "checked") ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" <?=($row['status'] == 1 ?"checked=\"checked\"" : "") ?> value="1" /> Mbyllur<br />
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" <?=($row['status'] == 0 ?"checked=\"checked\"" : "") ?> value="0" /> Hapur<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['status'] == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris answer is absolutely correct except both radio buttons having same id.
With all due respect to those who has answered, it is just my suggestion that no two elements in page should have same id.